# Docker add --insecure-registry for current session only

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Is it possible to add an `--insecure-registry=docker.my-registry` to the current session only with environment variables or similar?

I'd like to do some testing without changing my current Docker setup (for example I might not be able to restart the service).

Or any similar idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using the `docker:18.02.0-dind` Docker image (Docker in Docker).

I start the DID container:

`$ docker run -d --name did --privileged docker:18.02.0-dind --insecure-registry=my.insecure.reg`

Then I go into the running container:

`$ docker exec -it did /bin/sh`

And inside the running container I login to my insecure registry:

`/ # docker login -u me -p mypass my.insecure.reg
Login Succeeded`

In the running container I can now do some tests against my insecure registry.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad idea from a security point of view. If that were possible you (or any user) will be able to download images from an insecure registry that's not allowed by docker's sysadmin.

There is no concept of `per session` images in docker, any downloaded image will be available for all users

**edit**:

And to answer your question: No, it is not possible.

Comment: I agree, but still. It would be nice to have this. For example - testing a local registry in my network.